# How to make segmented color line in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working on a Flutter app. I want to bring the below image design in my app. For the second segmented line, I am using container and row widget. But for the first line, how can I approach for the design. Is it possible to achieve it in Flutter? Should I use widget or image(SVG,jpg) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in multiple ways:

1. You could make it an SVG and render it using [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)
2. You could make a `Row` with multiple `Container` as in:

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(color: Colors.yellow),
    ),
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(color: Colors.red),
    ),
  ]    
)
```

Changing the `color` and the `flex` value you will get the different segments with different sizes in proportionality. If you want all the segments to have the same width, just keep the same `flex` value or just use `Exapanded` instead of `Flex`.

3. You could draw it in a Canvas using a `CustomPaint`, but I wouldn't recommend it as this is much more difficult to develop and maintain, but its useful for more complex shapes and drawings.